# GetOptionChain from quantmod Package, how do you pull a full days worth of call/put options for past dates

Tags: r, call, put, quantmod

I am trying to pull 2 days worth of call/put option on AAPl.

I am using this command to save it as a csv, but I just need 2 current days worth of information:

> AAPL.csv <- getOptionChain("AAPL")

I have tried to merge commands from a different function but it doesn't seem to work. Code below:

> getOptionChain("AAPL",what=yahooQF(c("Bid","Ask")),from = as.Date("2013-01-30"), to = as.Date("2013-01-31"), from EOD_time = "9:30:00", to EOD_time = "15:00:00")

Any suggestions on how to just pull 2 days worth of option and equity data?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK yahoo doesn't provide historical data for options.  If it does, `getOptionChain` isn't intended to be used that way.

`getOptionChain` is more like `getQuote` than `getSymbols`.  It gets *quotes* for an option chain.  You can get quotes for multiple expirations and strikes, but you can't get a time series of prices.

The **Value** section of `help("getOptionChain")` tells you what the function returns:

> A named list containing two data.frames, one for calls and one for puts. If more than one expiration was requested, this two-element list will be contained within list of length length(Exp). Each element of this list will be named with the expiration month and year (for Yahoo sourced data).
>
> If Exp is set to NULL, all expirations will be returned. Not explicitly setting will only return the front month.